# Importing a haskell module from the parent directory

Tags: haskell, module

Given the following directory structure:

```
root
├── scripts
│   └── script1.hs
└── source
    ├── librarymodule.hs
    └── libraryconfig.txt
```

Where "librarymodule.hs" would be a library exporting multiple functions, where the output is influenced by the contents of the libraryconfig.txt file in his directory.

script1.hs is the file needing to use the functions declared in librarymodule.hs.

I can't find a solution on the internet for a structure as given above and hoped someone could help out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GHC has a `-i` option. Under `root/scripts/`, this will add `root/source/` to the search path:

```
ghc -i../source script1.hs
```

Also consider packaging your library using `cabal` so you can install it and use it anywhere without worrying about paths.

---

Here is a minimal example of a library with `data-files`:

```
source/
├── mylibrary.cabal
├── LibraryModule.hs
└── libraryconfig.txt
```

#### `mylibrary.cabal`

```
name: mylibrary
version: 0.0.1
build-type: Simple
cabal-version: >= 1.10
data-files: libraryconfig.txt

library
  exposed-modules: LibraryModule
  other-modules: Paths_mylibrary
  build-depends: base
  default-language: Haskell2010
```

#### `LibraryModule.hs`

```
module LibraryModule where

import Paths_mylibrary  -- This module will be generated by cabal

-- Some function that uses the data-file
printConfig :: IO ()
printConfig = do
  n <- getDataFileName "libraryconfig.txt"
  -- Paths_mylibrary.getDataFileName resolves paths for files associated with mylibrary
  c <- readFile n
  print c
```

See this link for information about the `Paths_*` module: https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#accessing-data-files-from-package-code

Now running `cabal install` should install `mylibrary`.

Then, under `scripts/script1.hs`, you can just run `ghc script1.hs`, using the library you installed.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but with this solution, "librarymodule" will not be able to read the contents of libraryconfig.txt anymore because that file used to be in the same directory. How would I use cabal in my situation? I can't figure it out

Comment: You have to change the path to `libraryconfig.txt` inside the library, either make it an absolute path, or make it configurable.

Comment: In a `cabal`  package you can specify [`data-files`](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#pkg-field-data-files) to install together with your package, and `cabal` provides your package a custom module that abstracts the location of those files.

Comment: I just created the cabal file inside "root" using the command "cabal init" and did "cabal install <cabalfile>" which created a dist folder, whats next?

Comment: did a stack --init solver, only it does still not see libraryconfig.txt even though it is included using data-files

Comment: I added a small example in my answer. I hope that will be sufficient to work but note that it will take time to learn these tools (`stack` or `cabal-install`) to fully understand what is happening.